# (Docker-Compose) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning when connecting node and postgres

Tags: node.js, postgresql, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I am trying to connect the containers for postgres and node. Here is my setup:

yml file:

```
version: "3"
services:
  postgresDB:
    image: postgres:alpine
    container_name: postgresDB
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_DB=myDB
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=Thisisngo1995!

  express-server:
    build: ./
    environment:
      - DB_SERVER=postgresDB
    links:
      - postgresDB
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:12

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY package.json ./

RUN npm install

COPY . . 

COPY ormconfig.docker.json ./ormconfig.json

EXPOSE 3000

CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

connect to postgres:

```
let { Pool, Client } = require("pg");

let postgres = new Pool({
  host: "postgresDB",
  port: 5432,
  user: "postgres",
  password: "Thisisngo1995!",
  database: "myDB",
});

module.exports = postgres;
```

and here is how I handled my endpoint:

```
exports.postgres_get_controller = (req, resp) => {
  console.log("Reached Here");

  postgres
    .query('SELECT * FROM public."People"')
    .then((results) => {
      console.log(results);
      resp.send({ allData: results.rows });
    })
    .catch((e) => console.log(e));
};
```

Whenever I try to touch the endpoint above, I get this error in the container:

[image]

Reasons why?

Note: I am able to have everything functioning on my local machine (without docker) simply by changing "host: localhost"

Comment: as you can see, your app tries to connect to `localhost` and you are not using `DB_HOST` environment variable. Get it from the env and place instead of localhost in postgres configuration.

Comment: @michalk sorry I was editing this document. I actually was using "postgresDB" as a host (The post has been updated). What would I need to put into DB_HOST if I already have this changed when connecting the client?

Comment: Your screenshoot shows that it still tries to connect to `localhost`.

Comment: @michalk I am uncertain as to what I would add/change from the codebase above. My host already points to the service called "postgresDB". How do I get it to not connect to 127.0.0.1?

If I may ask, specifically where and what I am not getting? That would be extremely helpful as I've been sitting on this for a few days.

Answer (score 0):

Your postgres database name and username should be the same

Comment: I am unsure as to how this would solve my issue. This only plays into the login credentials of the db (which is currently on the user: postgres, and the database name: myDB that was created. 

These shouldn't effect the communication between the app and postgres in container environment.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [docker-compose-wait](https://github.com/ufoscout/docker-compose-wait) to make sure interdependent services are launched in proper order.

See below on how to use it for your case.

1. update the final part of your `Dockerfile` as below;

```
# ...
# this will be used to check if DB is up
ADD https://github.com/ufoscout/docker-compose-wait/releases/download/2.7.3/wait ./wait
RUN chmod +x ./wait  


CMD ./wait && npm start
```

2. Update some parts of your `docker-compose.yml` as below:

```
express-server:
    build: ./
    environment:
      - DB_SERVER=postgresDB
      - WAIT_HOSTS=postgresDB:5432
      - WAIT_BEFORE_HOSTS=4
    links:
      - postgresDB
    depends_on:  
      - postgresDB
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
```

Comment: @albert-ngo if the answer helps, please remember to accept it. see [guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)